# z/OS - IMS/VTAM - INIT SELF FAILED WITH SENSE 08570002

Tags: mainframe, zos

I am a new mainframer and I have been given access to/control of a test system to play around in and learn. We have been trying to get IMS set up on the system but when I try to log into IMS 14 I get the error

`"INIT SELF FAILED WITH SENSE 08570002"`.

I have found that the error code means, `"The SSCP-PLU session is inactive."`

I am thinking that the issue is with the VTAM configuration but I am not sure what exactly needs to be fixed or where in z/OS to look for it.

I have asked around and dug through documentation with no luck so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Should the 'with' be 'without'?

Comment: it should thanks. I'll correct it.

Comment: Do you have a the message id? NEVER post a mainframe error message without the msgid :-)

Comment: This question should be moved to SuperUser as its more of a system administration issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message indicates an attempt was made to establish a connection from the SSCP (VTAM) and a Primary `LU` (an application) and the application was  not available.  This is done on behalf of an `SLU` (secondary logical unit) which is generally a terminal or printer.

This could the result of several situations but here are some common ones:

- An attempt was made to log on to something like `TSO`, `CICS`, `IMS`, ... before the VTAM ACB was actually opened.  You can attempt the request again later when the service is up
- To determine if the PLU (application is available) use the the VTAM command [`D NET,ID=`*vtamappl*](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.istopr0/did.htm) where vtamappl is the application ID your are trying to connect to.  This command is entered on the console directly or through a secondary means like SDSF.
- There may be a `LOGAPPL=` statement coded on the `LU` definition that tells VTAM to attempt to initiate a session when starting the LU.  In your case this would appear to be happening before the `PLU` (application) is up.  The `LU` definition (or generic definition) is in the `VTAMLST` concatenation.

This [manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cs3cod0/sc0857.htm) describes the sense code in more detail.

Comment: Thank you for this. I did some more digging and found out that I was on the wrong track pursuing this particular error. This has a lot more helpful info than I was able to find on my own.

Answer (score 0):

I know it was already checked and solved. But I would like to contribute for the people checking this in the future facing problems with the similar message being prompted:

Login screens are generated by VTAM STC, so first of all I would check if you can ping the LPAR to check if PAGENT task is up, which would not be possible without VTAM up. If you can ping it means VTAM is probably is up so you should check with your operations team to check for system replies in system console. It´s possible there is a reply not answered holding TSO to give you the login screen asking for your user and password, giving you the D0A4IT message instead.

The console can be checked via HMC and the command to check the replies is D R,R.

If you are on a sysplex environment, you could solve the problem in the other LPAR in the same plex, trying /D R,L to check replies on SDSF or #D R,L on IOF. And in case SDSF doesn't return to you the proper replies about the other LPARs in the same plex you could try as well /RO ,D R,L for the system to return to you only the replies related to the LPAR you're expecting you check.